# Unable to connect to SQL Server database in asp.net Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

When I get on the Security tab on the Web Site Administration Tool, I get this Error:

***There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name   or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.***

***The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.***

Here is the connectionStrings part in web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Verkoop.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="BestellingDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Verkoop.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is the membership part:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I've been searching the internet for solution for hours now, but can't find anything.
Can somebody please help?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

roleManager tag:

```
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: question `Is this a connection string for EF` or a `Connection string just for a sql server database..? sounds like you need to read this it will help  [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/)

Comment: Could you post **roleManager** tag located normally right below **memebrship** tag in **web.config**?

Comment: When I change the connection string I get an error that the connection DefaultConecction is missing or empty.

Comment: Win, I added the roleManager tag.

Answer (score 0):

> It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled.

Error message said **roleManager** is not enabled. Please enable it and test it again.

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    ...
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Do you have **SQL Server** instead of **LocalDB**? If so, could you create Verkoop database in **SQL Server**, and update the connection inside **web.config**?

Comment: I can't create a new SQL Server database, I get an error 40: could not open a connection to sql server. Sorry but I'm new to this, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Look at [SQL SERVER – Fix : Error : 40 – could not open a connection to SQL server.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/)